# In azure functions (js) POST request after async/await call does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, http-post, azure-functions

I am currently working with azure functions in javascript. In my function, I am first getting a specific element from my CosmoDB (this is the async/await part). I get a result and then I want to do an https POST request. However, my problem is, that it never finished the HTTPs request and I don't really know why. What am I doing wrong?

(As you can see I tried 2 different ways of doing the request, once with the standard https function and the commented out the part with npm request package. However, both ways won't work).

Here is my code:

```
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient;
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

const endpoint = "someEndpoint";
const masterKey = "anymasterkey";

const database = {
    "id": "Database"
};

const container = {
    "id": "Container1"
};

const databaseId = database.id;
const containerId = container.id;

const client = new CosmosClient({
    endpoint: endpoint,
    auth: {
        masterKey: masterKey
    }
});
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    const country = "de";
    const bban = 12345678;
    const querySpec = {
        query: "SELECT * FROM Container1 f WHERE  f.country = @country AND f.bban = @bban",
        parameters: [{
                name: "@country",
                value: country
            },
            {
                name: "@bban",
                value: bban

            }
        ]
    };
    getContainers(querySpec).then((results) => {
        const result = results[0];
            context.log('here before request');

            var options = {
                    host: 'example.com',
                    port: '80',
                    path: '/test',
                    method: 'POST'
            };

            // Set up the request
            var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
                    var body = "";
                    context.log('request');

                    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                            body += chunk;
                    });

                    res.on("end", () => {
                            context.res = body;
                            context.done();
                    });
            }).on("error", (error) => {
                    context.log('error');
                    context.res = {
                            status: 500,
                            body: error
                    };
                    context.done();
            });
            req.end();

            // request({
            //     baseUrl: 'someURL',
            //     port: 443,
            //     uri: 'someuri',
            //     method: 'POST',
            //     headers: {
            //         'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            //         'SOAPAction': 'someaction'
            //     },
            //     function (error, response, body) {
            //         context.log('inside request')
            //         if (error) {
            //             context.log('error', error);
            //         } else {
            //             context.log('response');
            //         }
            //     }
            // })
    })

};


async function getContainers(querySpec) {
    const {container, database} = await init();
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const {
            result: results
        } = await container.items.query(querySpec).toArray();
        resolve(results);
    })
}

async function init() {
    const {
        database
    } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({
        id: databaseId
    });
    const {
        container
    } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({
        id: containerId
    });
    return {
        database,
        container
    };
}
```

The last thing that happens is the print of "here before request". After that the function just does nothing until it timesout. So what am I doing wrong? Can't I just this combination of await/async and requests?

Comment: Do you see the call coming on the server?

Comment: I think I cannot check that as I run the function inside azure portal

Comment: when I just put the request in the function, its the same behaviour, so I am wondering if I cant send requests inside azure functions? Or what am I doing wrong? Is there a special way of sending requests here?

Comment: Does your post request take any body or not?

Comment: @TarunLalwani YES thank you! I totally forgot that I need to add a body in req.write(data)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you are not sending any data to the `POST` call. You need to have a `req.write` before the `req.end`

```js
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

That is why the POST call is failing for you. After this fix, it should work